# How to remove duplicate rows in postgresql with condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation, postgresql-9.1

I want to remove the duplicated rows where the condition is the updated date is less than the maximum updated date. However, I was not able to delete them.

My attempt:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_code, customer_id, id, sign_date ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS Row
  FROM fulfillment_bill_transactions WHERE active =1 AND transaction_type= 2
) dups
WHERE
dups.Row > 1
```

The result from my query shows the rows with the minimum updated date but not all updated dates except the maximum date.

Here is the example:

Table A:

| ID | Sign Date | Customer id | order code | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021/01/01 | 001 | AB | 2020/01/02 |
| A | 2021/01/01 | 001 | AB | 2020/01/03 |
| A | 2021/01/01 | 001 | AB | 2020/01/12 |
| B | 2021/01/03 | 002 | LL | 2020/02/02 |
| B | 2021/01/03 | 002 | LL | 2020/02/03 |
| B | 2020/01/03 | 002 | LL | 2020/02/04 |

Desired result:

| ID | Sign Date | Customer id | order code | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021/01/01 | 001 | AB | 2020/01/12 |
| B | 2020/01/03 | 002 | LL | 2020/02/04 |

Comment: according to OP description, seem like OP already get the data you need? if this is true then just insert this into new table then drop the old one.

Comment: `PARTITION BY order_code, customer_id, id, sign_date` --> `PARTITION BY id`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the duplicate rows except highest updated date then you can use the following query:

```
delete FROM fulfillment_bill_transactions t 
 WHERE exists (select 1 from fulfillment_bill_transactions tt
                where tt.id = t.id
                  AND tt.updated_date > t.updated_date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried it and the remaining row was not the one with highest updated date. It seems like this query only compare two rows.

I have updated the question, hope that you can help. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: It doesn't work well as well.
I figured out:
select * from (
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_code, customer_id, id, sign_date ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS Row
  FROM fulfillment_bill_transactions WHERE active =1 AND transaction_type= 2
) dups
where 
dups.Row > 1

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, if you want one row per group, then I recommend using `distinct on`.  For the sample data you have provided, this would be:

```
select distinct on (id) fbt.*
from fulfillment_bill_transactions fbt
order by id, date desc;
```

It is unclear what your code has to do with the question.  It refers to columns not in the sample data and the filtering conditions are not described in the question.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thanks for you help, I have updated the question. It should be clearer now.